# Dynamic links with user remove option

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add deleting users by another users (using dynamic links). I wrote this code:

```
$deleteAdVar = $_GET['delete']; 
if (isset($deleteAdVar)) { 
    $your_offers_delete = "UPDATE ads SET expired='1' WHERE id = '$deleteAdVar'"; 
}
```

and my link:

```
<a href="https://example.com/settings?delete='. $your_offers_id .'"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
```

Why this code isn't working? I tested this in PHPMyAdmin and it works.

Comment: Is your link inside PHP code (`echo`, a variable or something)? Because it looks like there are concatenation operators in there. Please show the full relevant code. Also, your SQL query is prone to SQL injection attacks. You should use prepared statements (I'd link the manual but no idea what kind of database / API you're using).

Comment: Yes, its in echo. Its only for learning on localhost, so SQL injection is impossible

Comment: practice good coding locally too, especially when putting it public when people may copy off it.